# I have many databound dropdowns on ASP.net. How to reuse the data binding code

Tags: c#-4.0

I have a private function as below

```
  private static void listSourceBind(SqlConnection sql,String table, String idColumn, String valueColumn, ref DropDownList dropDownList)
    {

        string sqlGetDataSource = "select "+ idColumn +", "+ valueColumn + " from "+ table;
        SqlCommand selectDataSource = new SqlCommand(sqlGetDataSource, sql);
        DataTable dataTable = new DataTable();
        SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(selectDataSource);
        adapter.Fill(dataTable);
        dropDownList.DataSource = table.ToString();
        dropDownList.DataSourceID = null;
        dropDownList.DataValueField = idColumn.ToString();
        dropDownList.DataTextField = valueColumn.ToString();
        dropDownList.DataBind();
    }
```

that I am calling from Page_Load function as

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    SqlConnection sql = new SqlConnection(sourceDB);
    listSourceBind(sql, "[SchemaName].[CInput]", "CID", "Desc", ref CInput);
}
```

However dropDownList.DataBind() method is throwing an excetion as below

> An exception of type 'System.Web.HttpException' occurred in
>   System.Web.dll but was not handled in user code
>       Additional information: DataBinding: 'System.Char' does not contain a property with the name 'InputDesc'.

However if I code as below it works perfectly fine. Problem is that there is a lot of repetitive code needed for each dropdown list

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SqlConnection sql = new SqlConnection(sourceDB);


        string sqlGetDataSource = "select CID, Desc from [SchemaName].[CInput]";
        SqlCommand selectDataSource = new SqlCommand(sqlGetDataSource, sql);
        DataTable table = new DataTable();
        SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(selectDataSource);
        adapter.Fill(table);
        CInput.DataSource = table;
        CInput.DataSourceID = null;
        CInput.DataValueField = "CID";
        CInput.DataTextField = "Desc";
        CInput.DataBind();


    }
```

Is there anyway I can write a function as I attempted above to avoid repetitive code

Comment: Your first method is obviously broken compared to the second: you're not doing anything with the data you read from the database, you're using a string as data-source instead. `table` has a different type in your other method. You don't need those `ToString` calls and that `ref` either.

Comment: C# code above is code behind for an aspx page which has drop down control. <asp:DropDownList ID="CInput" runat="server" DataSourceID="CDMDev" AppendDataBoundItems="True" DataMember="DefaultView" OnSelectedIndexChanged="CInput_SelectedIndexChanged">
        </asp:DropDownList>  There are many drop downs on page and I am trying to use a function instead of writing similar sequence of lines for each drop down. Please let me know what is broken in the function. I have tried without reusing ref qualifier for the function parameter, as well as not using ToString(), however I have got the same error

Comment: I already told you what's wrong: you're using a string as data-source instead of a `DataTable`. That `table` variable is a `DataTable` in your working code, but it's a `string` in the broken code. You'll want to use that `dataTable` variable as data-source instead.